# Is there a good pastebin (nopaste) around which can be self hosted?

Tags: pastebin

I'd like to set up a pastebin for our team, so we can share snippets easily. We don't want (and probably can't) paste production code in publicly accessible pastebins. So I started looking for pastebin servers and was quite surprised when I realized there are only very few around.

So here's the question: **What's the best pastebin which can be self hosted?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only one that I have come across so far: [3txt](http://code.google.com/p/3txt/)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but I've always liked [piratepad](http://piratepad.net/front-page/). Open source and allows real-time tracking.  Like multiplayer notepad.

Comment: Looks like etherpad.com is down too.

Answer (score -1):

Also check out *stikked* (it has some nice features): https://code.google.com/p/stikked/